# How to fix output not adding together?

Tags: c++

> Write a program that calculates how much a person would earn over a period of time if his or her salary is one penny the first day and two pennies the second day, and continues to double each day. The program should ask the user for the number of days.
>
> The output earnings should be displayed in a dollar amount, not the number of pennies.
>
> Input Validation: Do not accept a number less than 1 for the number of days worked.

Basically, the output displays the correct answer mathematically it just does not add them together. I am not sure on what to do to fix that issue.

```
//Declare Variables
int numDays = 1;
double money = 0.01;
double totalPay;

//Initialize or input i.e. set variable values
cin>>numDays;
//Map inputs -> outputs
while (numDays < 1)
{
    cout<<"Enter a positive value ONLY!\n";
    cin>>numDays;
}

for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++)
{
    cout<<"Pay = $"<<money;
    money *=2;
}

//Exit stage right or left!
return 0;
```

Expected Output

```
Pay·=·$0.03
```

My Output

```
Pay·=·$0.01Pay·=·$0.02
```

Comment: There is this absolutely lovely `totalPay` variable that is going unused. Looks like a great place to hold the sum.

Comment: Note that you have an infinite loop due to a lack of checked IO should the user type in something like "A" for `numDays`. You will want to check for this possibility, `clear` the error, and `ignore` the remainder of the user's input.

Comment: @user4581301 I understand that the totalPay variable is there. I put it there, but I am just not sure how to use it in the context of this code.

Comment: I've tried to use break; to end the for loop but it only outputs "Pay = $0.01" no matter what input I use.

Comment: I would ask a question should the output be added together...

Answer (score 0):

```
//System Libraries
#include <iostream>//Input/Output Library
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

//User Libraries

//Global Constants, no Global Variables are allowed
//Math/Physics/Conversions/Higher Dimensions - i.e. PI, e, etc...

//Function Prototypes

//Execution Begins Here!
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //Set the random number seed

    //Declare Variables
    int numDays = 1;
    double totalPay;
    double dayPay;
    double money = 1;

    //Initialize or input i.e. set variable values
    cin>>numDays;
    //Map inputs -> outputs
    while (numDays < 1)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a positive value ONLY!\n";
        cin>>numDays;

    }

    for(int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++)
    {
        dayPay = money / 100;
        totalPay += dayPay;
        money *=2;

    }

    cout<<"Pay = $"<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<totalPay;
    //Exit stage right or left!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks good, but 2 suggestions: 1) Change `double totalPay;` to `double totalPay = 0.0;` otherwise you can't be sure what value `totalPay` will hold when you start summing.2) Put the `cin>>numDays;` inside the `while` condition like `while (!(cin>>numDays) || numDays < 1)` so you can better trap typos and clean up with `cin.clear();` and `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`